# Oauth redirects me to http instead of https

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I work on a python3.6 app that uses flask and oauth2client and I deploy in flexible environment.

The command: `gcloud app browse` outputs the link: https://xxx.appspot.com

When I access it, I get redirected to the default route, which requires auth, then redirected to choose my google account after which I get redirected again to the default route but instead this time it's http instead of https.

This is the code for setting the default route:

```
@app.route("/")
    def index():
        return redirect(url_for('crud.home'))
```

And this is the controller method for the default route:

```
@crud.route('/home')
@oauth2.required
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Why is that? How can I make it redirect me back to https?

Comment: [oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) was deprecated and is not supported anymore.  [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/) and [oauthlib](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/) are recommended instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `url_for(..., _scheme="https")` Another way to achieve it would be to change server settings to rewrite all http requests with https.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `https://...` urls in your prefs?  Check it at:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project={your_project}

Comment: `Privacy policy URL  
Optional until you deploy your app`

And then I put the url to my app prefixed with https, but still doesn't work.